# Conda failing on MacOS (Sonoma 14.2) - M1 silicon Mac CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED

Tags: python-3.x, apple-m1, anaconda3, apple-silicon, macos-sonoma

conda was running fine on Sonoma 14.1.1
but with the update to Sonoma 14.2, it fails with the same error message on any command,
let alone creating new envs.

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url https://conda.anaconda.org-conda-forge/osx-arm64/osx-arm64/current_repodata.json

I have tried uninstalling conda and reinstalling it many times
Tried a few other solutions from the web, but sadly nothing worked :(